# How to set Circular Image View Background black in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview

Image View background reflect only inside the circle not outside the circle.
I tried so many things but not able do that.
Anybody please me.
Thanks!!

Comment: you have to create a resource drawable containing black border and set that drawable as background to your image View

Comment: or you can use card view if You are using Api Above 16.

Comment: "Image View background reflect only inside the circle not outside the circle."
So you are trying to change color behind your Image View? You can do that by changing a background of a parent view.

Comment: No I want to reflect background color only inside the image view circle but it is showing outside the circle as well. can u guys help me with some example.

Comment: can you post your xml code pls.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make an `.xml` file in drawable folder with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="oval">
     <solid
        android:color="@color/black"/>
</shape>
```

Then set this file as your background.

Comment: that is oval shape i want circle.

Comment: You can just add square measurements for your image view and it will appear as a circle. That is assign same width and height

Answer (score 7):

circle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <size android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="@color/black"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
</shape>
```

in ImageView
add this in

```
android:background="@drawable/circle"
```

thank you everyone for the help.
This code is working as I want.
thank You!!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using CircularImageView custom imageview class to make it circular. That's why background it getting apllied in cicular region only.

To solve it, do something like this,

```
<LineaLayout
     android:width="wrap_content"
     android:height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@color/black"/>


<!-- your circular CircularImageView here..!! -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Other solution you can do is, Use native `ImageView` and set its `android:src` by creating circular `bitmap` and use `android:background` black color and i would suggest to go with thise solution as you can avoid nested layouts.

I hope this hepls! Thanks.